# Can I create my own methods in a subclass using the template method design pattern?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

Whether using methods created outside the abstract class will disturb the Template Method design pattern? Will it still be Template Method pattern if I create *MyOwnMethod* and call it inside *a* method?

```
public abstract class TemplateMethodClass {

    public final void TemplateMethod() {
      a();
      b();
      c();
    }

    protected abstract void a();

    protected abstract void b();

    protected abstract void c();
}
```

```
public class SubClass extends TemplateMethodClass {

    public void MyOwnMethod() {
        System.out.println("I am not from template");
    }

    @Override
    protected void a() {
        MyOwnMethod();
    }

    @Override
    protected void b() {}

    

    @Override
    protected void c() {}
}
```

Comment: Why not having additional methods?

Comment: so should these additional methods be private to let user only call TemplateMethod() from main?

Comment: Why not be protected/private? (sorry for answering by asking but what's your question exactly)

Comment: okay so the answer is that doesn't matter and I can create my own methods and still keep the idea of  template method design pattern yes?

Comment: The code that I wrote is still template method design pattern yes?

Answer (score 1):

Template Method design pattern is about each subclass define [certain steps](https://medium.com/deciphering-deadlocks/what-is-template-method-design-pattern-cf99389c8658) in a skeleton

> The intent is to define the skeleton of an algorithm by postponing some steps to subclasses i.e. it lets subclasses define certain steps of an algorithm in their own way keeping the structure of the algorithm intact.

Steps can have one or multiple methods inside them, and if those methods are used only in subclass they will probably be private